# Problema ao criar script .sh para entrar em um diretório

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, unix

Estou criando um script .sh que o primeiro passo é entrar em um diretorio.

1.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/salariosbrasil/consulta-ninja
#git pull
pwd
```

esse diretório existe e mesmo assim o `cd` não funciona..

porém seu eu testar o `mkdir -p` com o mesmo nome do diretorio

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /home/salariosbrasil/consulta-ninja
cd /home/salariosbrasil/consulta-ninja
#git pull
pwd
```

ele cria outro diretório com o mesmo nome. só que com "?" no final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pergunta é:

- Como fazer para o `cd` funcionar?
- Porque ele cria outro diretório com    mesmo nome com "?" no final?

Comment: Qual mensagem que aparece quando você executa ? Direto na linha de comando funciona ?

Comment: Tem todo o aspecto de o teu ficheiro `script.sh` conter caracteres estranhos... (faz `od .c  script` e vê se aparece algum caracter estranho (exemplo `\r`) após o nome do directoria ; já agora: o que dá `ls -Q`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galera o problema era que eu criava o script no Windows e enviava para a maquina linux para executar o `.sh` :D :D

Criei o script no `vi` e funfou perfeitamente.

> "Unix uses different line feeds and carriage returns so can't read the
>   file you created on Windows. Hence it is seeing ^M as an illegal
>   character"

Answer (score 3):

O comando `cd` dentro do bash (.sh) é executado sob um subshell.

A ação é executada com êxito porém, no shell principal não surte efeito pois foi executado num contexto diferente.

Um truque simples é no momento de invocar o .sh

Normalmente fazemos isso

```
> ./file.sh
```

Pois bem, apenas adicione o comando *dot* com um espaço no começo:

```
> . ./file.sh
```

Alternativamente, pode trocar o *dot* por `source`

```
> source ./file.sh
```

O comando `.` (dot/period) é um sinônimo para o comando `source`. Esse comando carrega rotinas/funções de um arquivo para o shell corrente.

Executa num novo shell:

`./file.sh`

Retorna a execução no shell corrente:

`. file.sh`

Comment: Daniel, qual o efeito de se adicionar o ponto no inicio?

Comment: Editei no final.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez possa ser uma questão de nível de segurança...Você já deu uma olhada se o usuário de estra executando o script sem permissão para ler o tal diretório ?

> Uso essa rotina na empresa:

```
#!/bin/bash

make-dir(){
  sudo mkdir /solinftec
  sudo mkdir /solinftec/bin
  sudo mkdir /solinftec/log
  sudo mkdir /solinftec/sgpa-api
}

make-dir
```

Verifica também como funciona essa flag [-p] em sua distro, uso Fedora, e comigo não acontece isso.

> mkdir --help

```
Usage: mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
  -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
  -v, --verbose     print a message for each created directory
  -Z                   set SELinux security context of each created directory
                         to the default type
      --context[=CTX]  like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the SELinux
                         or SMACK security context to CTX
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mkdir>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) mkdir invocation'
```